# In Perl, are user-provided format specifiers always safe?

Tags: perl, security, printf

I would like to provide a user with access to writing their own format specifier.  I know that in some languages like C that there is a [format specifier attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack).

Are there any attacks against format specifiers in Perl for calling functions like `sprintf` and allowing the user to provide the format specifier?

In this example, can you contrive anything in `$unsafe_data` that would be unsafe in Perl?

```perl
return sprintf($unsafe_data, $internal_value);
```

Comment: @ikegami, can you give a long-string example?  Do you mean %-9999s or something?

Comment: I didn't downvote. And yes, except 10k is still quite small compared to what it could do.

Comment: In addition to large numbers, %n is nasty in that it modifies a variable. %p reveals addresses, which may or may potentially help hackers. And of course if the number of format conversions doesn't match the number of arguments, then the code will generate warnings (or die in the presence of 'use warnings FATAL').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are potentially unwanted effects.

- `%n` can be used to modify the arguments.
- Long strings can be generated.

  Can cause performance issues. Can result in brutal termination.
- Warnings can be generated.

  Noise. Exception if warnings are made fatal.
- Internal representation of scalars can be changed (e.g. by formatting `"abc"` using `%d`).

  Probably harmless, but could have subtle effects.

Comment: I'm not interested enough to check, but I imagine a clever use of `%n` and position parameters like `%2$d` may be fun.